# How to send data to MSMQ queue using Log4Net?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, log4net

I am trying to send a message to MSMQ  queue using Log4Net.I spent lot of time to understand the functionality from the net. But I couldn't find much help. The following is my source code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using log4net;
using log4net.Config;

namespace MQTest
{
    class Program
    {   
    private static readonly ILog ilogger = LogManager.GetLogger("");
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ilogger.Debug("This should go to the queue");
        ilogger.Fatal("This should go to the queue");
    }
    }
}
```

app.config

```
<log4net>
<appender name="MsmqAppender" type="MQTest.Appender.MsmqAppender, MQTest">
<queueName value="private$\test_queue"/>
<labelLayout value="LOG [%level] %date"/>
<layout type="log4net.Layout.XmlLayoutSchemaLog4j"/>
</appender>
<root>
  <level value="ALL"/>
   <appender-ref ref="MsmqAppender" />
</root>
</log4net>
```

When I debug the code, I have noticed that IsDebugEnabled = false, IsFatalEnabled =false etc.
 I don't know how to populate the above flags, while using MsmqAppender.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Your edited config isn't including the MsmqAppender, `<appender-ref ref="MsmqAppender" />`

Comment: Have you tried with log4net debugging enabled?

Comment: Yes, I have enabled log4net.Internal.Debug. But I didn't notice any issue in the console logs. System.Diagnostics.Trace  didn't write anything in the file.

Comment: You don't seem to be calling `XmlConfigurator.Configure()` in your main program

Comment: I tried calling XmlConfigurator.Configure, but it gave lot of exceptions. Should I call anyother methods for MsmqAppender?

Comment: You need to configure log4net. What exceptions are you getting?

Comment: Exceotion: log4net:ERROR Appender named [MsmqAppender] not found.

Comment: Is log4net supporting Msmqappender? http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html

Comment: You need to give the appender a name you can refer to it by, by adding an `<appender-ref>` element, eg `<appender-ref ref="MsmqAppender" />`

Answer (score 0):

You haven't got it set up right.

You've defined your appender and registered it in the config file, so when you want to log something you just use the `ILog` logger you get from the log manager, you don't need to create an instance of logMSMQ:

```
myLogger.Debug("This should go to the queue");
```

Looking at the appender and config, a couple of things stand out:

1. You should not be calling `XmlConfigurator.Configure();` from within the appender
2. You're not registering the appender in your config correctly: you need to [specify it by type and assembly namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26790149/43846), e.g.: `<appender name="MsmqAppender" type="AssemblyNamespace.MSMQTest.LogMSMQ, AssemblyNamespace">`
3. You have not specified it by name in the root logger configuration:

> ```
> <root>
>   <level value="ALL" />
>   <appender-ref ref="MsmqAppender" />
> </root>
> ```

While you're getting it set up, turn on [log4net internal debugging](http://haacked.com/archive/2006/09/27/Log4Net_Troubleshooting.aspx/) as it will help you see what's going on.

Comment: I have added the queue config, but still your code is not working <queueName value="private$\test_queue1"/>

Comment: What kind of working are we looking at? Can you update the code in the question and give details of what's not working?