# log4net TraceAppender prints the 'logger' part twice. How to avoid this behaviour?: "ClassName: datetime LEVEL ClassName - message"

Tags: c#, log4net

I am using the following configuration for log4net:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<log4net>
  <root>
    <level value="ALL" />
    <appender-ref ref="TraceAppender" />
    <appender-ref ref="file" />
  </root>
  <appender name="TraceAppender" type="log4net.Appender.TraceAppender">
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date %level %logger - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <appender name="file" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="loadbox.log" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Size" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
    <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
    <staticLogFileName value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
</log4net>
```

I instantiate and use my logger like:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()?.DeclaringType);

    public MyClass()
    {
        log.Debug($"{MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()?.Name}");
    }

}
```

But my log messages are written like:

```
13:45:37:913    MyClass: 2023-07-05 13:45:37,831 DEBUG MyClass - .ctor
                ^^^^^^^- I would like this part to be gone somehow
```

See Q in the above piece of code. How can I get rid of that very first `MyClass` print? This is what I see in the debug trace within visual studio 2022.
The output in the written file is completely fine though.

Comment: you have 2 appenders log into the same file.

Comment: I don't? There are two different appenders going to two different outputs

Answer (score 0):

It looks like at least some of that formatting is coming from [Trace.Write()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.trace.write?view=net-7.0#system-diagnostics-trace-write(system-string-system-string)) instead of `log4net`.  The bit you want to remove seems to be the `category`.

If you look at [TraceAppender](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-1.2.12/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.TraceAppender.html), the default is:

> Events are written using the System.Diagnostics.Trace.Write(string,string) method. The event's logger name is the default value for the category parameter of the Write method

The config for [Category](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-1.2.12/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.TraceAppender.Category.html) also says:

> Defaults to **%logger** which will use the logger name of the current LoggingEvent as the category parameter.

So you should be able to change this in your config file; e.g. something like:

`<category value="" />` (or another parameter; I'm not sure whether blank is okay here).

---

Another option if you don't mind the ordering but just don't want the repeating is to leave the category alone and instead drop `%logger` from your output:

`<conversionPattern value="%date %level - %message%newline" />`

Answer (score 0):

The complete solution is:

```
<appender name="TraceAppender" type="log4net.Appender.TraceAppender">
  <category value="LOG" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level - %message%newline%exception" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

See SO question [How do I stop the Visual Studio Output window displaying the logger name of log4net output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9174775/how-do-i-stop-the-visual-studio-output-window-displaying-the-logger-name-of-log4)